# How to restrict the touchesBegan and touchesEnded to one touch only?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view with two subviews:

1. A UIImageView
2. A small Custom View which is like a clock with hands that can be rotated.

I have written the code for rotation of hands in touchesBegan and touchesMoved of the custom clock-like view.

This custom view is placed over the image and I have added two-finger zoom,rotation,panGesture to the imageView.

Now My problem is whenever I one of my two finger touches hands of this clock-view, they move and rotate which I dont want.

I want to restrict their touches only when I am doing a single finger gesture on them and not two finger gesture on the image behind it.

**EDIT:** Here is my code to add the gesture

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)] autorelease];
panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `-(NSUInteger)numberOfTouches` of [`UIGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can tell you how many touches are placed on your view. Also this [Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) will may help you :)

Another way to go would be [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which can be configured with `numberOfTouchesRequired` to limit one recognizer to a special amount of fingers.

**EDIT**

I suggest you to use a private BOOL which locks interaction with one of the gesture recognizers, if another one is active.

With the new LLVM Compiler available in XCode 4 and later, you can declare @private variables in default categories inside your implementation (.m) file:

```
@interface YourClassName() {
  @private:
    BOOL interactionLockedByPanRecognizer;
    BOOL interactionLockedByGestureRecognizer;
}
@end

@implementation YourClassName
  ... your code ...
@end
```

Your method handling the pan interaction (I assume you'll do some kind of animation at the end to move around stuff):

```
- (void)handlePan:(id)sender
{
  if (interactionLockedByGestureRecognizer) return;

  interactionLockedByPanRecognizer = YES;
  ... your code ...
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                   [[sender view] setCenter:CGPointMake(finalX, finalY)];
                 } 
                 completion:^( BOOL finished ) {
                   interactionLockedByPanRecognizer = NO;
                 }
 ];
}
```

Now you just need to check inside your `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` if interactions are locked by the UIPanGestureRecognizer:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if (interactionLockedByPanRecognizer) return;
  interactionLockedByGestureRecognizer = YES;
  ... your code ...
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if (interactionLockedByPanRecognizer) return;
  ... your code ...
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if (interactionLockedByPanRecognizer) return;
  ... your code ...
  interactionLockedByGestureRecognizer = NO;
}
```

Comment: I have limited the gesture added to image to two(min and max) touches but the problem comes when one of  two touches falls on the custom view and that custom view takes it at its touches event.

Comment: Have you though about an BOOL which locks the UIGestureRecognizer on your "clock-view" if an interaction with your UIImageView happens?

Comment: NO I havent can you please elaborate on it more ?

Comment: Can you may post some code how your UIGestureRecognizer handle interaction? Than I can take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer.